# Python Date Formatting problems

Tags: python, django, datetime, unicode, xml-rpc

I am trying to format a Datetime object I received from an XmlRPC API. The date is formatted like this `(u'20121106T10:23:24')`. I tried doing this:

```
s = datetime.strptime(u'20121106T10:23:24', "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")
usedate = s.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

I get this exception:

```
time data "DateTime '20121106T10:23:24' at b556886c" does not match format '%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

I want the string to be in a `YYYY-MM-DD` format. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

**EDIT:** Sharing exact error:

```
ValueError at /idea/

time data "DateTime '20121106T10:23:24' at b556886c" does not match format '%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S'
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    

time data "DateTime '20121106T10:23:24' at b556886c" does not match format '%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Unless it is not a typo, you should be getting a SyntaxError

Comment: you have extra closing parenthesis in the middle, it should be like `datetime.strptime(u'20121106T10:23:24', "%Y%m%dT%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: sorry about that. Messed up when I was copying code over to my browser.

Comment: It works fine for me on Python2.7.3

Comment: Yep, works just fine for me too

Comment: My best guess is that you aren't actually using a string and are instead trying to convert the object itself (at least that is what the traceback seems to indcate). Not familiar with that API, but are you sure you are getting the string representation?

Comment: show us result of `print type(Datetime_object_received_from_an_XmlRPC_API)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I was calling repr instead of str on the DateTime object and it was causing some weird problems. Dumb mistake on my part. Thanks again guys :D. Upvoted you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb mistake on my part. I was calling repr instead of str and the methods didn't return the same thing. I was under the impression a datetime repr would equal the str.